# Build: failed_The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, arcore

I'm trying Arcore with Android Studio, and when I build my project, I get this error

> The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference
> 'android.support.design.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten.
> Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be
> updated manually to add support for androidx.

This is my build.gradle(:app) code

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.artest"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.23.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    implementation 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.0-alpha12'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

    }
```

I don't know what to do :/
Well, there's another error, about Google Sceneform Tool,

> Plugin Error: Plugin "Google Sceneform Tools (Beta)" is incompatible (supported only in IntelliJ IDEA).

But I think that's not the reason... maybe...

Comment: This may be unrelated, but I think minSdkVersion has to be at least 24 for ARCore, and there's a lot more dependencies than usual. Try first compiling some of the sample code and then pile on your extra dependacies on top one at a time to see which ones may be the problem...

Comment: @YinOrYan It worked! Succeeded to build but the app doesn't work in emulator without any error message.

Comment: Its important to get the feel of how the app is working with with a device in motion rather than an emulator. In addition, it helps to test on more than one device because the cameras are slightly different on every device...